# autohotkey: Comparison of two volumes - error in the result

Tags: autohotkey, string-comparison

**Hi, everyone**

the following code for A folder comparison, it's from here: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=44352&p=204630#p204630

```
#SingleInstance, Ignore
{
dir1 := ""
dir2 := ""
fileMask := ""
gosub, DoTheWork

Gui Add, ListBox, w530 r10 vfiles1, % "Dir1 = " dir1 "| |" list1
Gui Add, ListBox, w530 r10 vfiles2, % "Dir2 = " dir2 "| |" list2


Gui Add, Button, w50 gGuiOK default, OK
Gui Add, Button, x+10 w50 gGuiClose, Cancel
Gui,Add, Text, yp+5 x138,Dir1
Gui,Add, Edit, yp-3 x160 w90 vDir1,%dir1%
Gui,Add, Text, yp+2 x258,Dir2
Gui,Add, Edit, yp-3 x282 w90 vDir2,%dir2%
Gui,Add, Text, yp+2 x396,Mask
Gui,Add, Edit, yp-3 x423 w40 vFileMask,%fileMask%
Gui Add, Button, yp x483 w60 gGo, Go
;Gui Show, w1200
Gui Show, w550
Return

Go:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide 
    gosub, DoTheWork
    GuiControl,,files1,% "|Dir1 = " dir1 "| |" list1
    GuiControl,,files2,% "|Dir2 = " dir2 "| |" list2
return

GuiOK:
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp

DoTheWork:
filelist1 := filelist2 := ""    
list1 := list2 := ""    
Loop %dir1%\%fileMask%
{
If ( A_LoopFileName ~= "~\$")
        continue
    fileList1 .= A_LoopFileName . "`n"
    fnb1 := A_Index
}
StringTrimRight fileList1, fileList1, 1
Loop %dir2%\%fileMask%
{
    If ( A_LoopFileName ~= "~\$")
        continue
    fileList2 .= A_LoopFileName . "`n"
    fnb2 := A_Index
}
StringTrimRight fileList2, fileList2, 1

Sort fileList1
Sort fileList2
StringSplit files_1_, fileList1, `n
StringSplit files_2_, fileList2, `n
idxF1 := idxF2 := 1

Loop
{
    If (files_1_%idxF1% = files_2_%idxF2%)
    {
        ; We are in synch
        list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
        idxF1++
        list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
        idxF2++
    }
    Else
    {
        ; Either file at idxF1 or at idxF3 is missing, we must find which one
        If (files_1_%idxF1% > files_2_%idxF2%)
        {
            ; Missing in first list
            list1 .= " |"   ; Empty
            list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
            idxF2++
        }
        Else
        {
            ; Missing in second list
            list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
            idxF1++
            list2 .= " |"   ; Empty
        }
    }
    If (idxF1 > fnb1)
    {
        Loop % fnb2 - idxF2 + 1
        {
            list1 .= " |"   ; Empty
            list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
            idxF2++
        }
        Break
    }
    If (idxF2 > fnb2)
    {
        Loop % fnb1 - idxF1 + 1
        {
            list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
            idxF1++
            list2 .= " |"   ; Empty
        }
        Break
    }
}
StringTrimRight list1, list1, 1
StringTrimRight list2, list2, 1
Return
}
```

I added the next part to it, it contains 3 hotkey to set the folder path and file type:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 1
#IfWinActive, Comparison
$1::
ControlSetText, Edit1, E:\ask\work
ControlSetText, Edit2, E:\ask\backup
ControlSetText, Edit3, *.docx
ControlClick, Go, Comparison  
return
;;---------------------------------------------------  2

$2::
ControlSetText, Edit1, E:\ask\sales
ControlSetText, Edit2, E:\ask\work
ControlSetText, Edit3, *.pdf
ControlClick, Go, Comparison  
return
;;---------------------------------------------------  3

$3::
ControlSetText, Edit1, E:\ask\sales
ControlSetText, Edit2, E:\ask\backup
ControlSetText, Edit3, *.txt
ControlClick, Go, Comparison  
return
```

The code does not work well until the first time.
see in the attached picture(1).
[Everything is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYuJL.png)
But the following times are not correct
Unless you are reloading or if you close the program and reopen it
see The error in the attached picture.
[Bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLwsf.png)

Can anyone correct this error?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DoTheWork:
filelist1 := filelist2 := ""
list1 := list2 := ""
fnb1 := fnb2 := 0 ; <<<<< added: initialize the counters
Loop %dir1%\%fileMask%
{
If ( A_LoopFileName ~= "~\$")
        continue
    fileList1 .= A_LoopFileName . "`n"
    fnb1++ ; <<<<< changed: don't use A_Index because some files may be skipped
}
StringTrimRight fileList1, fileList1, 1
Loop %dir2%\%fileMask%
{
    If ( A_LoopFileName ~= "~\$")
        continue
    fileList2 .= A_LoopFileName . "`n"
    fnb2++ ; <<<<< changed: don't use A_Index because some files may be skipped
}
StringTrimRight fileList2, fileList2, 1

If (fnb1 = 0) && (fnb2 = 0) ; <<<<< added: early return
    Return

Sort fileList1
Sort fileList2
StringSplit files_1_, fileList1, `n
StringSplit files_2_, fileList2, `n
idxF1 := idxF2 := 1

Loop
{
    If (idxF1 > fnb1) ; <<<<< moved to the top of the loop
    {
        Loop % fnb2 - idxF2 + 1
        {
            list1 .= " |"   ; Empty
            list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
            idxF2++
        }
        Break
    }
    If (idxF2 > fnb2) ; <<<<< moved to the top of the loop
    {
        Loop % fnb1 - idxF1 + 1
        {
            list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
            idxF1++
            list2 .= " |"   ; Empty
        }
        Break
    }
    If (files_1_%idxF1% = files_2_%idxF2%)
    {
        ; We are in synch
        list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
        idxF1++
        list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
        idxF2++
    }
    Else
    {
        ; Either file at idxF1 or at idxF3 is missing, we must find which one
        If (files_1_%idxF1% > files_2_%idxF2%)
        {
            ; Missing in first list
            list1 .= " |"   ; Empty
            list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
            idxF2++
        }
        Else
        {
            ; Missing in second list
            list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
            idxF1++
            list2 .= " |"   ; Empty
        }
    }
}
StringTrimRight list1, list1, 1
StringTrimRight list2, list2, 1
Return
#IfWinActive, ask final
$1::
ControlSetText, Edit1, E:\ask\work
ControlSetText, Edit2, E:\ask\backup
ControlSetText, Edit3, *.docx
ControlClick, Go, Comp
return
;;---------------------------------------------------  2

$2::
ControlSetText, Edit1, E:\ask\sales
ControlSetText, Edit2, E:\ask\work
ControlSetText, Edit3, *.xlsx
ControlClick, Go, Comp 
return
;;---------------------------------------------------  3

$3::
ControlSetText, Edit1, E:\ask\sales
ControlSetText, Edit2, E:\ask\backup
ControlSetText, Edit3, *.txt
ControlClick, Go, Comp
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it slightly so that hotkeys now fill gui variables and send them to gui after which it executes automatically.

```
#SingleInstance, Ignore
{
dir1 := ""
dir2 := ""
fileMask := ""

;gosub, DoTheWork ;unnecessary here

Gui:
Gui Add, ListBox, w530 r10 vfiles1, % "Dir1 = " dir1 "| |" list1
Gui Add, ListBox, w530 r10 vfiles2, % "Dir2 = " dir2 "| |" list2

Gui Add, Button, w50 gGuiOK default, OK
Gui Add, Button, x+10 w50 gGuiClose, Cancel
Gui,Add, Text, yp+5 x138,Dir1
Gui,Add, Edit, yp-3 x160 w90 vDir1,%dir1%
Gui,Add, Text, yp+2 x258,Dir2
Gui,Add, Edit, yp-3 x282 w90 vDir2,%dir2%
Gui,Add, Text, yp+2 x396,Mask
Gui,Add, Edit, yp-3 x423 w40 vFileMask,%fileMask%
Gui Add, Button, yp x483 w60 gGo, Go
;Gui Show, w1200
Gui Show, w550
ControlClick, Go, ahk_exe AutoHotkey.exe ;;changed location of ControlClick from hotkeys to here
Return

Go:
    Gui, Submit, NoHide 
    gosub, DoTheWork
    GuiControl,,files1,% "|Dir1 = " dir1 "| |" list1
    GuiControl,,files2,% "|Dir2 = " dir2 "| |" list2
return

GuiOK:
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp

DoTheWork:
filelist1 := filelist2 := ""    
list1 := list2 := ""    
Loop %dir1%\%fileMask%
{
If ( A_LoopFileName ~= "~\$")
        continue
    fileList1 .= A_LoopFileName . "`n"
    fnb1 := A_Index
}
StringTrimRight fileList1, fileList1, 1
Loop %dir2%\%fileMask%
{
    If ( A_LoopFileName ~= "~\$")
        continue
    fileList2 .= A_LoopFileName . "`n"
    fnb2 := A_Index
}
StringTrimRight fileList2, fileList2, 1

Sort fileList1
Sort fileList2
StringSplit files_1_, fileList1, `n
StringSplit files_2_, fileList2, `n
idxF1 := idxF2 := 1

Loop
{
    If (files_1_%idxF1% = files_2_%idxF2%)
    {
        ; We are in synch
        list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
        idxF1++
        list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
        idxF2++
    }
    Else
    {
        ; Either file at idxF1 or at idxF3 is missing, we must find which one
        If (files_1_%idxF1% > files_2_%idxF2%)
        {
            ; Missing in first list
            list1 .= " |"   ; Empty
            list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
            idxF2++
        }
        Else
        {
            ; Missing in second list
            list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
            idxF1++
            list2 .= " |"   ; Empty
        }
    }
    If (idxF1 > fnb1)
    {
        Loop % fnb2 - idxF2 + 1
        {
            list1 .= " |"   ; Empty
            list2 .= files_2_%idxF2% . "|"
            idxF2++
        }
        Break
    }
    If (idxF2 > fnb2)
    {
        Loop % fnb1 - idxF1 + 1
        {
            list1 .= files_1_%idxF1% . "|"
            idxF1++
            list2 .= " |"   ; Empty
        }
        Break
    }
}
StringTrimRight list1, list1, 1
StringTrimRight list2, list2, 1
Return

SetTitleMatchMode, 1
#IfWinActive, Comparison
$1::
Gui,Destroy
Dir1 := "E:\ask\work"
Dir2 := "E:\ask\backup"
FileMask := "*.docx"
GoSub, Gui
return

;;---------------------------------------------------  2
$2::
Gui,Destroy
Dir1 := "E:\ask\work"
Dir2 := "E:\ask\backup"
FileMask := ".pdf"
GoSub, Gui
return

;;---------------------------------------------------  2
$3::
Gui,Destroy
Dir1 := "E:\ask\work"
Dir2 := "E:\ask\backup"
FileMask := "*.txt"
GoSub, Gui
return
#IfWinActive
}
```

Comment: this Answers for Mr. **just me** from autohotkey Forums: [Link](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=48230&p=215966#p215966)